# Python Zipfile writes full path to file

Tags: python, zip

I am making a zipfile in Python 3 like this:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("/path/to/zipfile.zip", mode='w')
try:
    zf.write("/path/to/original.file")
finally:
    zf.close()
```

However, when I unzip it, I get this structure:

```
path
└── to
    └── original.file
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: But what actually do you expect to get?

Comment: @Georgy `original.file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("/path/to/zipfile.zip", mode='w')
try:
    os.chdir("/path/to/original file folder")
    zf.write("original.file")
finally:
    zf.close()
```

Comment: I think OP wants the basename only while unzipping.

Comment: In my testing, the file being compressed is already in the same folder as the script.

Comment: @Theo Then try replacing the full path and just use zf.write("original.file")?

Comment: @Rakesh It has to work with any path, though. I managed to solve it by `chdir()`ing into the directory and then using the relative path `./original.file`.